# Dependencies of directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, angular-directive

I am using a third party-directive in my angular app. I need to extend the functionality with my own directive and ran into some troubles with the order in which the directives are instanciated.

The directives are intended to be used like this:

```
<third-party-dir ng-repeat="item in items" my-additional-dir>
    <some-content />
</third-party-dir>
```

Whenever an Item is added i want to execute some code depending on `third-party-dir`. However `my-additional-dir` is instanciated first and thus the `third-party-dir`-`link` function wasn't executed yet. I tried to add dependencies by using "require" but since `thirdPartyDir` does not use a controller (only the link function), angular is throwing an error.

```
.directive('myAdditionalDir', function(){
    return {
        require: '^thirdPartyDir'
        restrict: 'A'
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        if (scope.$last){
            //some code            
        }    

        }
    }
})

Error: [$compile: ctreq] Controller 'thirdPartyDir', required by directive 'myAdditionalDir', can't be found!
```

I looked into pre- and post-link functions, but the default link-function is already a post-link function. Any hints on how i can "wait" for the `third-party-dir` to be instanciated before executing the code within my directive?

Comment: When you require a directive, that directive's controller is injected as 4th argument in the sub directive's link function. I think the error you are facing is because angular looks for the parent directive's controller and couldn't find it.

Comment: Option `require` work only for directive with *controller*. If `third-party-dir` don't have *controller*, you can't use `require: '^thirdPartyDir'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When declaring your directive you can use `priority` to decide the order in which the link functions are called.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-

The post-links are called in order from lowest to highest.  You could look at the third-party source code to spot its order and set yours lower.

```
.directive('myAdditionalDir', function(){
    return {
        priority: -1
```

Comment: looks good on the initial page-load, but for some reason the order is different when a new DOM-node is added by ng-repeat ?!

Comment: nvm, check your link for the following: "Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order." Using a positive value for priority works fine.

Comment: Yes, sorry I can't see all your code, so just use the value which works for you.